# How to add thin wispy clouds or fog to my blender 3d scene of building

Tags: particles

When I add a smoke particles (clouds) it seems to be thick and an a certain elevation.  I'd like to have thin clouds around the tops of buildings.  Is there a different method?

Comment: Less particles should make less smoke within the domain. Or try reducing density or density scale on the texture or material influence to make it more transparent.

Answer (score 3):

## Blender internal:

You could try the [*Cloud Generator addon*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Cloud_Gen). This is good for making 3D volumetric clouds, but note that it will only work for BI, as cycles does not yet have volumetric rendering.

1. Enable the *Cloud generator addon* in *User preferences > Addons*. This addon is bundled with blender by default, so it should be in the list:

   [image]
2. Create a bounding shape for your cloud, then press *Generate cloud* in *3D view > Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) > Cloud generator* with it selected:

   [image]

This will create a point cloud for the cloud and setup the volume materials.

For more info take a look at [this tutorial on blender cookie](https://vimeo.com/17142380).

## Cycles:

Because cycles does not yet have volumetrics, you will have to fake it.
Here are some options:

- Render the clouds in BI and mix in the compositor
- Use a transparent plane with an image texture (may look okay when seen from a distance)

Related questions:

- [Volumetric Shading in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/934/volumetric-shading-in-cycles)
- [Creating volumetric lighting (crepuscular rays) in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/creating-volumetric-lighting-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles)
- [Rendering smoke in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/smoke-in-cycles/927#927)